# HTML / CSS Structure not behaving the way its expected

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have some html code and I am trying to get this:

parts are:

**.main-wrapper** - I need to keep this in absolute so that the elements inside work with percentage sizing. I don't want to use vh or vw.

**.main** - This needs to always be 100% height and width.

**.tbar** - needs to be always visible on the left of .main

**.side** - Will toggle sliding from the left and push .bar and .main when it opens.

I hope I'm explaining it properly.

Here is what I've tried but it's not right:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title></title>

    <style>

    .main-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 59px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        border-left: 3px solid blue;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .main-wrapper .side {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    .main-wrapper .tbar {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .main-wrapper .main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand">
        <span class="toggle-leftbar navbar-brand"><button id="togglebtn">Toggle</button></span>
        <a class="sidebar-toggle mr-3" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="side">Side Here</div>
        <div class=tbar>TBar</div>
        <div class="main">Main Here</div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
           $('.side').toggle();
        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get this parts to do what I need?

Comment: `.main-wrapper - I need to keep this in absolute so that the elements inside work with percentage sizing. I don't want to use vh or vw.` . No no no. `elements inside` work with percentage sizing. Don't use absolute positioning for something that doesn't need it. Also, for layout check flexbox or css grid.

Comment: I've tried changing it to relative or none and the 100% height stops working...it all shinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also define  `$('.side').toggle();` but when you click Toggle Button that time work `$('.side').toggle();` so you try **on click function** inside add this code like this..

---

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        
            $( "#togglebtn" ).click(function() {
              $('.side').toggle();
            });

});
```

```css
   .main-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 59px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        border-left: 3px solid blue;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .main-wrapper .side {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    .main-wrapper .tbar {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .main-wrapper .main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
     <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand">
        <span class="toggle-leftbar navbar-brand"><button id="togglebtn">Toggle</button></span>
        <a class="sidebar-toggle mr-3" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="side">Side Here</div>
        <div class=tbar>TBar</div>
        <div class="main">Main Here</div>
      </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Almost there...just one thing...the blue border belongs to .main and I need it to be on the right on .tbar...at the moment .main is going under .tbar ... And the text main is currently at the bottom

Comment: can you attach the screen shot?   Exactly how looks? I don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet above" you will see a blue border (far left) ... that is part of .main and should be at the right of .tbar with is missing...it should be at the right of .side. I can't attach images yet sorry :(